# How do I publish ROS messages to ROS_INFO?

Tags: ros, rosout, ros-info, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have a node that is producing messages of the type 'sensor_msgs' which I would like to see in my /rosout log. My approach was to add a statement similar to the following:

```
ROS_INFO(sensorMessage);
```

This produces type conversion errors that I might be able to work around but I feel like there would be an easier solution.

Edit: Here is the full function, with the ROS_INFO statement at the bottom:

```
void publishData(const Imu::IMUData &data) {
  sensor_msgs::Imu imu;
  sensor_msgs::MagneticField field;
  sensor_msgs::FluidPressure pressure;

  //  assume we have all of these since they were requested
  /// @todo: Replace this with a mode graceful failure...
  assert(data.fields & Imu::IMUData::Accelerometer);
  assert(data.fields & Imu::IMUData::Magnetometer);
  assert(data.fields & Imu::IMUData::Barometer);
  assert(data.fields & Imu::IMUData::Gyroscope);
  
  //  timestamp identically
  imu.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  imu.header.frame_id = frameId;
  field.header.stamp = imu.header.stamp;
  field.header.frame_id = frameId;
  pressure.header.stamp = imu.header.stamp;
  pressure.header.frame_id = frameId;

  imu.orientation_covariance[0] =
      -1; //  orientation data is on a separate topic

  imu.linear_acceleration.x = data.accel[0] * kEarthGravity;
  imu.linear_acceleration.y = data.accel[1] * kEarthGravity;
  imu.linear_acceleration.z = data.accel[2] * kEarthGravity;
  imu.angular_velocity.x = data.gyro[0];
  imu.angular_velocity.y = data.gyro[1];
  imu.angular_velocity.z = data.gyro[2];

  field.magnetic_field.x = data.mag[0];
  field.magnetic_field.y = data.mag[1];
  field.magnetic_field.z = data.mag[2];

  pressure.fluid_pressure = data.pressure;

  //  publish
  pubIMU.publish(imu);
  ROS_INFO(imu);                                 <-------I want to publish imu data 
  pubMag.publish(field);
  pubPressure.publish(pressure);
  if (imuDiag) {
    imuDiag->tick(imu.header.stamp);
  }
}

Thanks!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261121/how-do-i-publish-ros-messages-to-ros_info?/) by [corcorant](https://answers.ros.org/users/29721/corcorant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2017-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_INFO is used like printf, so you can't just pass a message as a parameter. It should be some kind of string. I would recommend creating the message you need like this:

```
ROS_INFO("--IMU MESSAGE--");
ROS_INFO("stamp: %d", imu.header.stamp);
ROS_INFO("linear acceleration x: %f", imu.linear_acceleration.x);
etc..
ROS_INFO("---------------");
```

I have not compiled/tested the code, but I think it should work. (You might need to cast some values)

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3